# On Xubuntu 13.10 AR8162 Wired internet disabled on Asus 1015e-ds03

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, asus

I have an Asus 1015e-dso3 laptop. It came with Ubuntu 12.04 installed, and everything was fine, except that the laptop came very strangely partitioned. There was about 150gb worth of space that wasn't being used and no partition manager would let me access so I could use it. Finally being a KDE fan at heart I decided to wipe it clean & just install Kubuntu 12.04 Everything is working fine except for some reason I only have wireless internet & can't get my wired internet working.

I have enabled backports and performed all updates and my laptop tells me there are no restricted drivers available.

I've tried to provide as much info as possible So here's the output of Varun's Wireless script, it seems to do a pretty thorough job, even though it's my wired internet that's giving me trouble you can find that here http://paste.ubuntu.com/7277571/

The output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
`*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 6c:71:d9:7f:9b:9d
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.2.0-58-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.111 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memory:f7d80000-f7d8ffff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)`
```

The output of `ifconfig -a`

```
`lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:5406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:542537 (542.5 KB)  TX bytes:542537 (542.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:71:d9:7f:9b:9d  
      inet addr:192.168.1.111  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::6e71:d9ff:fe7f:9b9d/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:14215278 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4228474 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:20103309745 (20.1 GB)  TX bytes:495036621 (495.0 MB)`
```